# How do I determine which type of RAM my laptop uses?

Tags: memory, ddr3, ddr2

I have a HP Compaq Presario CQ56-103ST laptop and I want to learn whether it uses DDR2 or DDR3 RAM.

- In [its official web page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02675489&cc=ad&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001), it is said that it has 3 GB DDR2 (1 x 1024 MB + 1 x 2048 MB).
  (Obviously not so. It has only 2GB of RAM installed in a single slot.)
- In [this page](http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/HP+-+Compaq-memory/Presario+CQ50+Series/Presario+CQ56+(DDR2)-upgrades.html), it is said that it uses DDR2 PC2-6400, DDR2 (non-ECC).
- Windows says that memory size is 2GB, doesn't tell about its type.
  (Yes, it is indeed 2GB.)
- CPU-Z says that it is 2GB DDR2 RAM.
  [image: Memory Tab]
  [image: CPU Tab] [image: Mainboard Tab]
  *(CPU and Mainboard)*
- Pictures I shot doesn't reveal any information to me.
  [image: Picture 1] [image: Picture 2]

It looks like to be DDR2, but I can't make sure about that. I don't have the user manual of the laptop with me right now. Can anyone please confirm it for me? I'm going to purchase new RAM units, I need to know the RAM type. If I order a wrong type of RAM, it will be a lot of trouble for me.

Comment: 1) As it is this question will be closed as 'to localised'. Might want to edit it to be more useful to future visitors. E.g. a 'How to I determine which type of RAM my laptop uses'.  2) Doesn't it list this in the manual?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I identify hardware I am unfamiliar with on my computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer)

Comment: How to know how many channel supported? my loptop is Asus N56DP.

Comment: You read the laptops manual. For currently sold laptops it usually is up to 2 channels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Laptop_SODIMM_DDR_Memory_Comparison_V2.svg
[image]

Then count the pins next to the notch to confirm that it is DDR2.
(Or check your picture. Enlarged it is easier to count and there are 20 pins before the notch).

Also useful to known: PC6400 aka DDR2-800 runs at 400 MHz (which explains your CPU-Z value)

Comment: since of course DDR  means double data rate ;p

Comment: How to know how many channel supported? (my loptop is Asus N56DP)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PC6400 = 6400 MB/sec = 800MHz so it is DDR2, since lowest DDR3 is 1066MHz.A useful utility to determine the hardware and software in a Windows computer is Lavalys's Everest, whose newer name is Aida64 and can be downloaded from www.lavalys.com It can work from Windows 95 up to Windows 8, without even having all the drivers installed. This is useful for as technicians, so we know which drivers to download without having to visit the manufacturers site. It is especially useful for unknown build-to-order computers and laptops where there is no a single official manufacturer! It even provides links to manufacturer's site to download the driver!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which kind of memory your laptop contains, your safest bet is taking a look at the manual. Search for "(your laptop model) manual" in any search engine, in most cases it will give you useful results.

In your case, using the above search query results in [the manual](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02657369.pdf), which states (p. 44) that this model supports *DDR2 for the Intel* version, and *DDR3 for the AMD* version. CPU-Z shows an Intel CPU/chipsest for yours, so it should hold **DDR2**.

Even easier? Take the memory out, and have a look. The label should state its type.

Comment: The OP has taken the memory out and the post shows pictures of it....with a HP part number sticker over the relevant information. Nice details on the intel/AMD DDR2/3 part though.